# Is there a way to override Chrome's “Request Desktop Site” option?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

I would like to know if there is a way to override Chrome's "Request Desktop Site" option when the user visits a mobile site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that feature does is spoof the user agent of the browser to make it look like it's coming from a desktop.
Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tz24aCo6F3I

If you're making a responsive site, it shouldn't affect your design since it would base the layout on the screen size. If you're attempting to use browser detection however, this would affect how your site is displayed to the user since it will see the user as a regular desktop browser. There's really not a way around the user-agent spoofing other than looking at the screen size and making assumptions about the browser type.